# sqlite - join tables or subquery?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following tables:

```
create table part_category(id text primary key);

create table parts (id text primary key not null,
                    cat references part_category(id)); 

create table products (id text primary key not null);

create table product_parts (product references products(id),
                            part references parts(id), 
                            qty integer);

create table locations (id text primary key not null,
                        stage text not null);

create table stock (part references parts(id),
                    cat references part_category(id),
                    location references locations(id),
                    qty integer,
                    date text);

create table orders (part references parts(id),
                     cat references parts(cat),
                     product references products(id),
                     qty integer not null default 0, 
                     date_order text,
                     date_due text,
                     date_done text,
                     status boolean,
                     primary key(part, product, date_due));
```

And I'd like to have this returned from a `select`:

Part, Category, Product, Qty, Date Ordered, Date Due, **qty of material**, **qty of stock**, **qty of wip**

The columns bolded above are the ones that I can't figure out. Below is my select with the subquery where I'm trying to get the **qty of stock**.

The problem is the query is returning zero for everything.

```
orders = db.execute('''select distinct o.part, o.cat, o.product, o.qty, 
o.date_order, o.date_due, o.date_done, 
julianday(date_due) - julianday(date_order) as days_due, 
(select stock.qty from stock, orders 
where stock.part = orders.part and stock.location = 'stock' and orders.status = 1)
as qty_stock
from orders as o join stock as s on o.part = s.part 
where o.status = 1  
order by o.date_due asc, o.product asc, o.part asc''').fetchall()
```

Example output is

```
for item in orders:
    print item['part'], item['qty'], item['qty_stock']


SOME_PART_NUMBER 3 0
```

But should be:

```
SOME_PART_NUMBER 3 22
```

Comment: Maybe some quotes need to be quoted? `stock.location = ''stock''`

Comment: I'm surprised that that code even runs.

Answer (score 0):

The title says "join tables **OR** subquery". The sql does both. I'm not sayin' that's the problem. But it certainly adds a level of complexity that could be error prone. You could try removing the subquery and replace it with `s.qty`, then add `s.location = "stock"` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I'll rephrase the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about your business logic.
I guess this is what you want.

```
select distinct o.part, o.cat, o.product, o.qty, 
        o.date_order, o.date_due, o.date_done, 
        julianday(date_due) - julianday(date_order) as days_due, 
        qs.stockQuantity as qty_stock
    from orders as o 
    join stock as s on o.part = s.part
    left join (select stock.part, sum(stock.qty) stockQuantity
                from stock ss 
                join orders oo on ss.part = oo.part
                where ss.location = 'stock' and oo.status = 1
                group by stock.part
                ) qs on qs.part = o.part
    where o.status = 1  
    order by o.date_due asc, o.product asc, o.part asc
```